# Jaspersoft : how to call visualize js using proxy server (external to internal)

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, jasperserver

We are using Jaspersoft to generate and retrieve report. This server is running in internal network (private IP address). We have a proxy server (external server) in Web Api to receive visualize js and all other request. Then we forward this request to Jaspersoft server. Our approch is given below:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
    uriBuilder.Host = "internal address";

    request.RequestUri = uriBuilder.Uri;
    if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get) {
        request.Content = null;
    }

    var response = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(request,
            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
    return response;
}
```

This approch can download visualize.js successfully, but when we call `visualize()` method from visualize.js, for some request jaspersoft server returning `404-Not Found`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why the error occurs. But I hope the problem is you are creating `HttpClient` object for every request. You should create this object once and use this object. Try this

```
//Initiate HttpClient object here
private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
    uriBuilder.Host = "internal address";

    request.RequestUri = uriBuilder.Uri;
    if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get) {
        request.Content = null;
    }

    var response = await _client.SendAsync(request,
            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Let me try and then get back to you.